# Prove that certain $\alpha_m:C_n\rightarrow C_n$ is automorphism if $\gcd(m,n)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, gcd-and-lcm, coprime

I need help with the following abstract algebra problem:

> Given $C_n$ the cyclic group of order $n$, we define the map
> \begin{align*}   \alpha_m : C_n &\to C_n\\   x &\mapsto x^m \end{align*} Prove that $\alpha_m$ is automorfism if and only if
> $gcd(m,n)=1$.

The first part is proving that $\alpha_m$ is homomorfism, which is easy seen by doing this:
$$\alpha_m(xy)=(xy)^m=x^my^m=\alpha_m(x)\alpha_m(y).$$
Now I need to prove it's injective and surjective. For injectivity, I assume there are some $x$ and $y$ that verify $x^m=y^m$. And here's where I'm stucked. Maybe considering $m=kn+r$? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :** $\gcd(n,m)=1$ implies that there exists $u,v$ such that $un+vm=1$. Thus

$$x=x^{1}=x^{un+vm} = (x^n)^u (x^m)^v = (x^m)^v = (y^m)^v = (y^m)^v (y^n)^u = y^{mv+un} = y$$

Notice also that proving injectivity is enough, since the map is a morphism from a finite group into itself.

**Edit :** For the converse, you can prove that if $\alpha_m$ is surjective, then $\gcd(n,m)=1$. Let's write $(C_n, \times)$ as $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, +)$. Then if $\alpha_m$ is surjective, there exists $x \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$mx=1 \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$
which means that there exists $k$ such that $mx + kn = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, so $\gcd(n,m)=1$.

Comment: So I dont need to prove surjectivity? How can I be sure about that? Thanks!!

Comment: If $f : A \rightarrow B$ is a map between two finite sets $A$ and $B$ that have the same number of elements, then $f$ is bijective iff $f$ is surjective iff $f$ is injective.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks!!

Comment: This proves that $gcd(m,n)=1$ implies $\alpha_m$ injective, but what about the reverse implication?

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's perfect.